# Laravel Eloquent ORM alternative to pluck

Tags: laravel, eloquent

New to ORMs in general, looking for guidance.

I have 3 tables, and I'm trying to get a list of ID's from my Question table which belongs to my Survey Table (From within my Survey Controller). I can use ORM and pluck, but that only returns the first ID. Any idea how I would go about getting all of the question ID's corresponding to the below query?

When I display the page in a forelse on the view page, it will only show for the first ID over and over. Any Ideas?

```
$ball = $survey->questions->pluck('id');
```

Which is used to feed

```
  $chart = Charts::database($answer->whereIn('question_id', $ball)->get(), 'bar', 'material')
    ->title("")
    ->colors(['#F5A623', '#A9D8D3'])
    ->elementLabel("Answers")
    ->dimensions(0, 250)
    ->groupBy('answer');
```

Survey Controller

```
class Survey extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'user_id'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $table = 'surveys';

    public function questions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function answers(){
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }


}
```

Answer Controller

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class answer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'answer'
    ];

    protected $table = 'answers';

    public function survey(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
    }

    public function question(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }

}
```

Question Controller

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
    'option_name' => 'array',
    ];

    protected $fillable =['title', 'question_type', 'option_name', 'user_id'];
    public function survey(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function answers(){
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }

    protected $table = 'questions';
}
```

Comment: hi in you database, have you many questions for the record of `$survey`??

Comment: The error doesn't appear to be with my pluck logic. It's in my database query for my chart that is only returning the first instance of ID.

Comment: Yes that's what i said, may be the `survey` that you work with has only one question in the database !!

Answer (score 1):

As I'm not completely sure of the issue and the code is incomplete here are some ideas.

- `$balls = $survey->questions()->pluck('id');` will create a collection 
  from the DB.
- Use `->whereIn('question_id', $balls)->get()`  when dealing with a collection/array of IDs.
- You can add a `belongsTo(Question::class)` to your `Answer`  allowing for  `$answer->question`